# Why interfaced DDR3 memory working slow as compared to on-chip memory in FPGA?

Tags: memory, fpga

I am using MAX10 FPGA and have interfaced DDR3 memory. I have noticed that my DDR3 Memory is working slow as compared to on-chip memory. I came to know about this, as I wrote a blinking LEDs program, and for same delay function with on-chip memory it is working faster as compared to DDR3 memory. What can be done possibly to increase speed? And what might possibly be wrong? My system clock is running at 50MHz.
P.S. There are no Instruction or Data Caches in my system.

Answer (score 1):

First,your function is not pipeline function as your description.Because you do something with memory and then blinking the LED.Every thing run in sequence.

In this case,you should estimate the response time and throughout of your memory.For example,you read a data from memory and then do a add function,and do this 10 times.If you always read memory after add function,your sum time consumption is about 10*response time + 10 add function time.

The difference is memory response time.Inner ram's response time can be 1 cycle at 50MHz.But DDR3 memory should be about 80 ns. That's the difference.

But you can change your module to pipeline pattern.Read/write data and do your other function parallel.And r/w DDR ahead.That's like cache in PC. This can save some time.

By the way,DDR throughout is highly depends on your function pattern.If you read or write data at the sequence order address, then you will get a bigger throughout.

After all,external memory's throughout and response time can never greater then internal memory.

Forgive my English.